# Login Failed Paypal Android Studio

Tags: android, paypal

A few weeks ago I was working on PayPal payments, everything was going perfectly, but after a few days I started getting an error "login error" and I don't know why this error happens. This is the code.

Given this, I would like you to actually help me, because I have not known why this is happening for days and before, everything was normal.
I am using Java in Android Studio and everything started to work fully functional, but when I wanted to log in, that error began to appear, I was watching videos on how to fix it, but they are more than 7 years old and I could not solve it. I will show my error code and I will also show the code of my activity I will not be making any modifications so that they see everything as I see it.

dependency: implementation 'com.paypal.sdk: paypal-android-sdk: 2.15.3'

the activity code is:

```
    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE=7171;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config= new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
    Button btnPagar;
    EditText txtMonto;
    String monto ="";

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        btnPagar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPagar);
        txtMonto= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMonto);
        btnPagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                procesarPago();
            }
        });
    }

    private void procesarPago() {
        monto = txtMonto.getText().toString();
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(monto)), "MXN", "PAGADO", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){

            } else if (resultCode==PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {


            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Code error:

````
  org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
      at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.cs.m(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.fi.d(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.ce.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.onResponse(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.perf.network.zzh.onResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.8:22)
      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2021-02-26 13:58:20.038 27031-27235/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:
2021-02-26 13:58:20.649 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
2021-02-26 13:58:20.650 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-02-26 13:58:20.656 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ```
````

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK as seems to be the case, it's deprecated and should not be used for anything. There is no support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet with these sort of connection errors is to grab the log cat output and look for an error message with a debug_id and then contact Merchant Support. They can look in to the specific thing that's happening on the backend.